# Bind View model to view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have general question about binding in the view of the view model.

We are working on wizard and in the initialize page all the pages are called 
before the wizard starts (see the code below) so in the view  we are using the following code to do the relation with `this.Datacontext = mvm;`, currently when this code is called the objects in the view model which bind to the screen (from the `viewModel`) is empty since this called in the beginning of the pages creation but the view model will be updated with data later in the program.

Will the screen be updated with the data when the bounded items are filled?

```
 public partial class EPreviewGraphSelector : UserControl
        {
           MyViewModel mvm = new viewModel(); 
            public EPreviewGraphSelector()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.Datacontext = mvm;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the screen will be updated with the data when the bounded items is filled ?

Provided your ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly, the UI should update.

Comment: Thanks,assume that I have list view which is read only and filled in the view model during the progress on the wizard ,the binding in the xaml to the list is sufficient? or should I do something in addition ,I ask it since the when the dataContext are getting the model view this list is empty...

Comment: Does the viewModel get filled with the correct data inside the constructor, or do you have to call a specific method to get them to load first?

Comment: @mileyH If you raise PropertyChanged for the list, or use an ObservableCollection<T>, it'll work fine.

Comment: THanks you ,If you can provide an simple example for list box are updated in the screen in MVVM it will be great :)